# Azure App Service のグローバルIPアドレス

Tags: azure

Azure 上に作成した App Service について

App Service から国内の別サイトにアクセスしたいのですが、
リージョンが Japan East / West でもApp Serviceに割り当てられるグローバルIPアドレスの国籍が US と判定され、
海外からのアクセスを拒否しているサイトにアクセス出来ない場合があります。
何か対応方法はあるでしょうか。